# php-form-builder-class Checkbox Value

Tags: php, arrays

I am using the php-form-builder-class and am trying to pass in an array to the values to mark the box as checked however the array doesn't work if there are keys. Is there anyway to remove or return the array as

```
array("0", "1", "2", "3")
```

instead of

```
Array ( [0] => "0" [1] => "1" [2] => "2" [3] => "3")
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array you are dumping is equivalent to the first array (that is there are always "keys" in PHP even though they are ordered integers by default).  Maybe you can try using [`array_values($array)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: yeah, array_keys is useful also